# Pycharm use web driver to access safari

Tags: python, selenium, safari, webdriver, pycharm

I develop a simple python script in `Pycharm`to access safari on my MacBook Pro.

My safari version is: Version 11.0.3 (12604.5.6.1.1)

My MacOS version is : 10.12.6 (16G1212)

[image: image here]

The hint seem to tell me to all remote automation, but actually I have already enable on develop tag.

[image: image here]

I'm confused, any body can help.

Comment: Please don't post text as pictures. [Edit] your question and add the source code and the exception traceback.

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of the code running?